# I have this Dataframe, Using Transform Function how can I assign them index values as new row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform, analytics

[This is the Dataset, I want to add a column named Index which will start number for every person from 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdIX6.png)

This provides count, but I want to provide Index values for eg: 1,2,3 for one person, and new person comes again 1,2,3,4 etc.

```
new_df['Index']=new_df.groupby('Name Of Reporting Person')['Name Of Reporting Person'].transform('count')
```

Comment: IIUC you are looking for [```groupby.cumcount()```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + 1 (as it starts counting from 0 I believe)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `groupby().cumcount()` is what you need:

```
new_df['Index']=new_df.groupby('Name Of Reporting Person')['Name Of Reporting Person'].cumcount()
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html)

```
new_df['Index'] = new_df.groupby('Name Of Reporting Person').ngroup()+1
```